# Laravel preparing the database before a test for a model with many dependencies, is there a better way?

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit

I am using Laravel 5.2 for my web app and the bundled testing tools which extend PHPUnit.

I am writing a test for a page that performs an update on a model. The test checks that one of the model's attributes hasn't changed prior to submitting the form in order to prevent two users from updating the model if they had it both open in their browser at the same time.

The test requires the use of a model in my Laravel web app, namely `App\Models\Application`, and I am using factories to create some fake data for this model. The `Application` model has many `belongsTo` relationships, which in turn requires that the related model is created within the test using factories prior to the creation of the `Application` model.

For example, the `Application` model has a `belongsTo` relationship with `Applicant`, so I need to create an `Applicant` model with a factory prior to creating an `Application` and an `Applicant` also has `belongsTo` relationships with `User`, which I also need to create before ... you get the idea.

So, in short, I am creating several model instances due to the relationship dependencies of one model which I want to test.

So this has left me wondering if I am taking the wrong approach? Is there a more simple approach where I  only create the model that is under test?

Here's the code from my test:

```
/** 
 * @test
 */
public function throw_exception_when_application_status_is_modified_after_submission()
{
    /**
     * Arrange
     */
    // create roles
    factory(Role::class, 'admin')->create();
    factory(Role::class, 'applicant')->create();

    // create admin user
    $adminUser = factory(User::class)->create();
    $adminUser->attachRole(Role::whereName('admin')->first());
    // create applicant user
    $applicantUser = factory(User::class)->create();
    $applicantUser->attachRole(Role::whereName('applicant')->first());

    // create organisation with type
    $organisationType = factory(OrganisationType::class)->create();
    $organisation = factory(Organisation::class)->create();
    $organisation->organisationTypes()->attach($organisation->id);

    // create sub application
    $subApplication = factory(ExperienceLetter::class)->create();

    // create applicant
    $applicant = factory(Applicant::class)->create([
        'user_id' => $applicantUser->id
    ]);

    // create application
    $application = factory(Application::class)->make([
        'status' => 'pending',
        'application_id' => $subApplication->id,
        'application_type' => 'App\Models\ExperienceLetter',
        'organisation_id' => $organisation->id,
        'applicant_id' => $applicant->id,
    ]);    

    // prep data
    $data = [
        'action' => 'accept',
        'details' => 'email sent',
        'application_id' => $application->id,
        'application_status' => 'pending',
        'verification' => 'email',
    ];

    /**
     * Act
     */
    // log in
    $this->actingAs($adminUser);

    // alter status before call()
    $application->status = 'verification';
    $application->save();

    $response = $this->call('POST', route('admin.application.action.store'), $data);

    /**
     * Assert
     */
    $this->assertEquals(302, $response->status());
    // assertSessionHasErrors
}
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you creating all of those because of foreign key constraints?  If you just want to check that one model without any relations then `Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();` is your friend:

```
/** 
 * @test
 */
public function throw_exception_when_application_status_is_modified_after_submission()
{
    \Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
    /**
     * Arrange
     */
    // create admin user
    $adminUser = factory(User::class)->create();
    $adminUser->attachRole(factory(Role::class, 'admin')->create());

    // create application
    $application = factory(Application::class)->make([
        'status' => 'pending',
        'application_id' => 0,
        'application_type' => 'App\Models\ExperienceLetter',
        'organisation_id' => 0,
        'applicant_id' => 0,
    ]);    

    // prep data
    $data = [
        'action' => 'accept',
        'details' => 'email sent',
        'application_id' => $application->id,
        'application_status' => 'pending',
        'verification' => 'email',
    ];

    /**
     * Act
     */
    // log in
    $this->actingAs($adminUser);

    // alter status before call()
    $application->status = 'verification';
    $application->save();

    $response = $this->call('POST', route('admin.application.action.store'), $data);

    \Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
    /**
     * Assert
     */
    $this->assertEquals(302, $response->status());
    // assertSessionHasErrors
}
```

Comment: Hi Eric. Thanks for your response. That's exactly the reason! I'll give this a shot soon and see how it works out. Would this work for a MySQL testing DB and and SQLite in memory testing DB?

Comment: I am currently using Laravel 5.2 and can't seem to find this method in the code base. Getting this error when running my tests `Error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Schema\MySqlBuilder::disableForeignKeyConstraints()`. Have also tried `\DB::getSchemaBuilder()->disableForeignKeyConstraints();` with same results. Any ideas?

Comment: The API docs state is exists in 5.2 here: https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Builder.html but when I look at `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder` in my code base I can't find the method. Perhaps I need to update the minor version of Laravel?

Comment: Running `composer update laravel/framework` has updated the minor version and seems to have done the trick. `Removing laravel/framework (v5.2.31)` `Installing laravel/framework (v5.2.45)` the test is now passing with the `\Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();` as you suggested.

Comment: Quick question, although this achieves what I originally asked in my question, i.e. "Is there a more simple approach where I only create the model that is under test" - is this considered "bad practice" at all? I know with testing and programming, in general, there is not always a *right* way to do something but I'm just wondering if there are any implications that I should consider before taking on this approach throughout my whole test suite?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's bad practice as long as you are consistent. You would just want make sure that if you omit something or mock (if you're using mocks) and object in a test it's because you already have tests for that thing to make sure you're not overlooking something that will fail in a live environment before reaching the scenario you are testing. Besides that, adding more tests is never a bad idea, especially for edge cases like yours.

Comment: Thanks for your help Eric.